# find the numbers which has more difference than others

Tags: algorithm, graph, numbers

I have a queue contains messages of different counts & I have script to read the queue and process the messages. My problem is: some of the queue has very larger number of messages & it exceeding than an usual. So, to improve the processing I would like to do process the queues which are all having the greater counts. If the queues are having the linear differences(eg: 1000, 1200, 1300, 1800, 1900) I want to process complete queue. If suppose the counts being like (1000, 1200, 1300, 1800, 1900, 4000, 4500, 4900, 5200) - here 4000+ are very larger queues So I want to take only these queues.

I hope some math calculations Standard deviation etc. will help but I have no idea how to approach it.

Comment: Please specify a bit more exactly what you mean by "get the numbers". Do you mean you would like to receive "groups" of numbers? Or do you just want to get the numbers that lie on the border between two groups?

Comment: Here my problem is I cant keep the definite number(5 or 10) as vast difference & also while I am doing it my queue keeps increasing by some other process[Queue is very dynamic]

Comment: Then you would have to give us a few more examples, becasue it is unclear to me what outcomes are possible.

Comment: Letsay 6 queues are there. They are 62, 69, 100, 5300, 5400, 6000, from this, should take 5300, 5400, 6000 to process.
Proces 'll operat to reduce cnt of que. Atsome point it'll reduce 5000,5100,5700 like tat.
Meanwhile some new que get added 5323,5400,5900... Now'll get ques as62,69,100,5000,5100,5700,5323,5400,5900.
Now want to take ly 5000,5100,5700,5323,5400,5900 to proces. Another case if al ques 'r high
6200,6900,5700,5000,5100,5700,5323,5400,5900 want al queues to proces.
Another case-if queue is 62,69,100,5000,5100,5700,5323,5400,5900,10000,14000,16000 want only 10000, 14000, 16000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start like that:

- Take the first number (in this case 1000) and devide every number in your array by this one and save that fraction in accordance to every number.
- Take the log with the base which you define as being "vastly different" (say 5 or 10) of every of these fractions and save them with accordance to every number.
- Put all numbers in a group for which the log of the fraction lies between -1 and 1 and remove those numbers from the array of all numbers.
- Start over with the remaning numbers and continue until you only have 1 (which you would put into a new group) or no numbers left.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start from sorting.
2. Gather statistics of differences between neighbor elements.
3. Select several "big" jumps

Definition of "big" can be different. If you know their number (e.g. there will be only two groups), just select appropriate number of the biggest jumps (1 less than number of groups). Alternatively you can take some percent of big jumps or analyse average and variation to select some threshold.

Comment: Sort the values, define a window, calculate the mean and stddiff for every window and calculate the chance for the element right from the window. If chance is too low, consider jump "big".